# How do I use CI4 "model" class methods to return the contents of a list of selected fields from a table?

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter-4

CodeIgniter4 provides a new Model class that helpfully eliminates several typical CRUD coding requirements. I could use the built-in "Query Builder" toolset but I'd like to learn to use the new CI4 Model methods. But, I can't see how to simply return a set of selected columns from a record set. The "$data = $model->findColumn('columnName')" method only selects a single column. I tried using an array of column names as the argument - which almost every other CI4 class recognizes - but that produces the error:

"Argument 1 passed to CodeIgniter\BaseModel::findColumn() must be of the type string, array given.".

```
    $data = $model->findColumn(['title', 'content'])->where('memID', $memID);
```

I also see no way to "chain" the findColumn() method, which feels like a hack anyway. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading the CI4 docs several more times I now see that the built-in Model class methods, like find(), are only for very basic queries, and for setting parameters that will be used in every instance of the class, like the table name. Also, if you have a very simple query your model won't need to load the Query Builder class which should provide some speed advantage.

But those methods built into the Model Class do not support, for example, selecting a subset of the available columns in the database.

Thus, the Query Builder class methods are not an alternative to the CI4 Model's built-in methods. Instead, they can be used in most typical queries.

Reading the CI4 docs caused me to believe the basic methods of the model class, like find()  or findAll(), were separate from the query builder methods and had to be invoked separately. I now see the query builder methods are available to any Model object that I create - and can be used together in the same query, like:

```
    $data = $model->select('title, text')->where('memID', $memID)->findAll();
```

Please let me know if my conclusion is not correct.